# Execute a stored procedure in Azure Data Factory V2 if two pipelines are succesfull executed

Tags: azure-data-factory

[Azure Data Factory IF condition Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W8Yf.png)

What I'm trying to do is executing a stored produre, however it should only be executed if the two preceding "Pipelines" are successfully executed. *See Image URL above.*

I'm struggling with the correct expression in the "IF condition".
I'm trying to accomplish something like:
**IF** *TriggerCopyAX* is *succesfull* AND *TriggerCopyNav* is *succesfull* Continue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute pipeline is a type of activity, what you want to do is chain activities, not pipelines. You can configure activity dependency with the dependsOn property. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#control-activity

Example:

```
"dependsOn": [ 
    { 
        "activity": "YourActivityName", 
        "dependencyConditions": [ "Succeeded" ] 
    }
]
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

Yes that works.
So basically what I did:
1. Did not use the "If condition".
2. I dragged the two "execute pipelines"  directly to the stored procedure.
3. When I looked at the code behind the stored procedure element I saw the "dependsOn" property is automatically used.

```
"dependsOn": [
        {
            "activity": "TriggerCopy_AX",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        },
        {
            "activity": "TriggerCopy_NAV",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Thats what I meant to say! Glad to help :)